# Evenly sized partitions in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

All,

My database has several years worth of temporal data that I am currently partitioning my the month. The problem is that some months there are hundreds of millions of records while other months only have a handful. What I would like to do is partition based on the number of records in the partition table so that each partition is equal. My question is, how would one go about doing this using a dynamic trigger function or maybe even a rule of some sort?

Thanks,
Adam